# Rendering not working as expected could be HDRI issue

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a pupil who is rendering their text but it is showing as grey on the front of the text

I have rendered it in cycles.

I wanted the front to be the same as the rest of the writing

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe it comes from the lighting or HDRI, hard to tell, maybe share your file?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: cannot find where to attach the file

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there.

Comment: Looks like a GPU issue (colored noise) and also, the front face is just a plane face, so the angle of the camera affects how the reflection looks right there